# UIMA installation: exception in thread "main" java.lang.classcastexception

Tags: java, eclipse, classcastexception, uima

I am trying to configuire eclipse (in Windows) with `UIMA` using this [tutorial](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.2.2-incubating/docs/html/overview_and_setup/overview_and_setup.html#ugr.ovv.eclipse_setup.example_code) . I have followed each step exactly and finaly am able to import `uimaj-example` in eclipse with no error. but I am unable to import the UIMA packages in my java class. (The import org.apache.uima.analysis_component cannot be resolved). The project structure is as following:

[image: unable to import uima package in-spite of adding to classpath]

In UIMA-SDK folder, the read-me suggested to test the installation, run the `documentAnalyzer.bat` (or .sh) file located in the bin subdirectory. 
the documentAnalyzer.sh run just for a moment and then disappears showing this:

[image]
(Sorry for the blur image, i wasnt able to take clear screenshot as it appeared only for a second)

I have already

- imported UIMA in build path of my project
- added UIMA_HOME variable in eclipse `java/classpath`
- set the Enviroment variable path of directory

I am new to Java and UIMA. I might be doing something wrong, clearly. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: The ClassCastException is because the code is trying make a change that isn't supported in Java 9 and later releases. [This bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA-5754) says it is fixed in releases 2.10.3 and 3.0.1

Comment: Note that the tutorial link you provided points to an ancient version - the current one is at https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-current/overview_and_setup.html - although you might want to stick to https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.10.3/overview_and_setup.html for the moment - depending on which components you eventually plan to use.